# Socat open TCP only when PTY opened

Tags: tcp, pty, socat

I am trying to link a virtual PTY with a remote device which accepts TCP connections on port 23. The opening and closing of the socket on the target device is a *significant* event and part of the operation of the device.

I am currently trying to use `socat` to do the job, with:

```
socat pty,link=/dev/ttyACM99,raw tcp:192.168.0.15:23
```

It works, in that I can open `/dev/ttyACM99` and read/write data to the device - however as soon as the `socat` command is run the TCP port is opened, and it only closes when `socat` is terminated.

What I need is that the TCP port doesn't open until some other software (it matters not what) opens `/dev/ttyACM99`. When `/dev/ttyACM99` is closed the TCP connection should then disconnect.

I can't find anything in the `socat` manual pages or from googling (though it's quite a tricky thing to google for) that says this is even possible with `socat`, and I really don't want to have to go to the hassle of writing my own piping program (though I could if I really need to).

---

**Update:**

I found the `wait-slave` parameter to the PTY pipe which does what I want - however it now terminates `socat` on closing of the PTY which is far from ideal.

```
socat pty,link=/dev/ttyACM99,raw,wait-slave tcp:192.168.0.15:23
```

Is there an option like `wait-slave` or that can go with `wait-slave` that will just close the target socket instead of closing the whole program? At the moment I am running it in a `while 'true'` which seems to work for now, but isn't ideal.